# Index seek and Table scan takes the same time to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a table with the structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CountryCode] [NVARCHAR](2) NOT NULL DEFAULT (N'GB'),
    [CreationDate] [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [NVARCHAR](256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [LastSignIn] [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnd] [DATETIMEOFFSET](7) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail] [NVARCHAR](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName] [NVARCHAR](256) NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [TimeZone] [NVARCHAR](64) NOT NULL DEFAULT (N'Europe/London'),
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [NVARCHAR](256) NULL,
    [LastInfoUpdate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
)
```

I have around a million rows in that table, and I want to apply a nonclustered index to the `[LastInfoUpdate]` column.

So I've created a non-clustered index using this command:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ProductVendor_VendorID1   
ON [dbo].[TestUsers] (LastInfoUpdate)
INCLUDE(Email)
```

And once I'm trying to run simple query like that:

```
  SELECT [LastInfoUpdate]
  FROM [dbo].[TestUsers]
  WHERE [LastInfoUpdate] >= GETUTCDATE()
```

I just get the same result in timing as without index. According to SQL Server Profiler with db does index seek while using index and just use less cpu resources in comparison with case without index but what is important for me it's time. What time the same? What am I doing wrong?

[Execution Plan of table scan](https://prnt.sc/l9yxmj)

[Execution plan of Index Scan](https://prnt.sc/l9yx0z)

[Index seek Execution Plan file](https://files.fm/u/3jh62hq3)

Comment: How many rows does this statement return?

Comment: @RBarryYoung around half of million

Comment: Then that's why it takes the same time.  Almost all of the time is just in the data transmission time of 500,000 rows.

Comment: Guess you're right. So how i can eliminate executing time of this?

Comment: Please, could you show the execution plan of both queries?

Comment: That depends on what your real goal is.  If you are just trying to measure query overhead, then insert the results into a temp table instead of displaying them.  If your goal is to make this query faster, then you should change it to only return the rows you actually need.

Comment: My goal is to retrieve lastInfoUpdate for last ten minutes get respective user ids and after that base of recieved info updates other entities

Comment: @JesúsLópez for Index scan https://prnt.sc/l9yx0z

Comment: @JesúsLópez https://prnt.sc/l9yxmj

Comment: So you want a _descending_ index on `LastInfoUpdate` so the most recent rows are always first? Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a better way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: @HABO Yes, so not to go through all records. Include as XML?

Comment: @HABO https://files.fm/u/3jh62hq3

Comment: The query plans you linked don't match the query of your question. The query plans are for this query: `SELECT EventId, EventDate FROM Users WHERE EventDate <= GETUTCDATE()`. And there is no index with EventDate key that includes EventId

Comment: Please, use the following page to paste query plans: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: would you please fix the question?

Answer (score 1):

Just create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Users_EventDate ON Users(EventDate)
INCLUDE (EventId)
```

And the following query will be fast:

```
SELECT EventId, EventDate
FROM Users
WHERE EventDate <= GETUTCDATE()
```

Because the index is a covering index.

The key of a covering index must include columns referenced in `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses. And the covering index must include all columns referenced on the `SELECT` list.

The query you posted doesn't match to the query plans you linked. The query plans are for the above query.

Another thing to take into account is the number of records returned by the query. If they are many, the query cannot be fast enough, because it needs to read all the data and send it to the network.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ColumnStore` index. It is faster when you want to get some range of columns:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX 
    [csi_User_LastInfoUpdate_Email] ON 
    [dbo].[User] ( [LastInfoUpdate], [Email] )WITH 
    (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0) ON [PRIMARY]
```

[An article about column store index.](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/columnstore-indexes-in-sql-server-2012/)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but in my version columnstore doesn't supported

Answer (score 0):

"WHERE [LastInfoUpdate] >= GETUTCDATE()" might return a lot of results. Tablescan can in this case be faster than index seek and subsequent adding information from the tabledata.
By adding the queried information to the index you can avoid the costly subsequent looks into tabledata.

Comment: but i need for example find all dates that greater than now plus 10 minutes and searcing it on millions rows can be the case. What possible ways of doing it in sql?

Comment: Would (LastInfoUpdate,EventDateTime)  as column definition of the index help? You would have less data to look at, and the index could provide all the data. That should definitly be faster than a tablescan

Comment: No. Or it's a bad idea trying to create an index based on datetime field?

Comment: why should that be a bad idea? datetime can be ordered, you do an ordered query so the index at least if you start with the datetime-field as attrubutelist should help to process the query